# Strange pair of type declarations

Tags: ada

Okay, so it may not be *that* strange, but I'm really new to Ada. In my job, I am translating legacy Ada to C, and have come across something that I haven't seen yet. I searched around, but couldn't really find it; here it is.

```
type Discrete_Names is ( ENUM_POS_4,  --label names in an enum
                         ENUM_POS_5,  --that evaluate to 4, 5, and 6
                         ENUM_POS_6); --respectively
type Discrete_Array_Type is Array (Discrete_Names) of Discrete.Does_Not_Matter
```

Side note—the Discrete.Does_Not_Matter just references another type in a different library.

It would be great if someone could just help me get my bearings and just figure out what is going on here.

Comment: The enumeration type is the index type for the array - simple as that. You can loop over the array with `for i in Discrete_Names loop ... my_array(i) := ...` and you can't index anything outside the array. Oh, and it's Ada, not ADA.

Comment: Also, please mention if any [*Enumeration Representation Clauses*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-4.html) are lurking nearby.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what's going on here. There are no Enumeration Representation Clauses nearby, or any in this module at all.

Comment: `Discrete_Names’Pos (ENUM_POS_4)` will always be 0. If you need to get the value 5 from `ENUM_POS_5` you could use an enumeration representation clause and GNAT’s `’Enum_Rep` [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gnat_rm/Enum_005fRep.html). In the past I’ve just used an array of integer indexed by the enum.

Comment: As [noted](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-4.html), an instance of "`Unchecked_Conversion` may be used to query the internal codes used for an enumeration type." The result should be the same as `'Enum_Rep` You might check to see what your implementation is using.

Comment: @BrianDrummond  - you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is quite simple.  In Ada arrays can be indexed by any discrete type, that is, integers, characters or enumeration types (your case).  The line

```
type Discrete_Array_Type is Array (Discrete_Names) of Does_Not_Matter
```

declares `Discrete_Array_Type` as the type of an array that contains values of type `Does_Not_Matter` and it is indexed by values of type `Discrete_Names`.

If your doubt stems from the fact that `ENUM_POS_4` has `Pos` equal to 4 -- so that it seems that the first index of the array is 4 and not 0 -- my suggestion is... forget about it.  The compiler will take care of that.  In Ada arrays can start from any index.  For example, if you say

```
type Array_Foo is array(Positive range <>) of Characters;
Bar : Array_Foo(10..15);
```

Bar will be just 6 entries long (not 16) and when you access `Bar(12)` the compiler -- behind the scenes -- will remove the initial offset "10" to "12" so that you will access the third memory location reserved to `Bar`. (Actually, I think that for the sake of efficiency it will add 12 to the address of Bar diminished by 10 times the integer sizes, but this is a detail...)

My personal experience is that in cases like this you should not consider the enumerative type like a "integer in disguise" (although it will be internally represented by an integer), but like a type of its own that can be used to index an array.  Let the compiler worry about the internal low-level details.